# How to use combination of Layouts to get widgets at desired position

Tags: android, layout, widget, uibuilder

we are confused with designing interface file for android,we have made user interface with Absolute layout and used "dip" instead of "px" (for different screen size issue) ,but it looks like,Absolute layout  has been depreciated,and developer.android, recommends not to use Absolute layout

So other option we have is to use
1.Linear layout
2.Frame layout 
3.Table Layout
But we are unable to bring Combination of above layouts so,that we can make button/widgets to proper position we need
How do we make widgets to desired position of screen with above said layouts and making them compatible with different screen sizes we have in android devices
would like to get a generic answer about same,

Tools used are: DrawDroid

Comment: We can't tell you how to do your layout, if you don't describe what the layout you want is.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Suppose the screen be, http://iappphone.s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots/390801497/mzl.hquhvcoq.480x480-75.jpg ,Now ,if i use linear layout things get aligned to some part of screen, how do we solve that? ,Is it solved by adjusting Left margin,top margin,right margin,bottom margin ,and keeping this values as "dip" rather than px,Recently Android released screens with different aspect ratio,how do we deal with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best layout to use if you were considering an `AbsoluteLayout` is a `RelativeLayout`.

Check out the Android Common Layout Objects page and its explanation of how to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout).

Without more information on what you are trying to do, expanding this answer anymore is useless.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer .I used LinearLayout and used combination of margin right,left,top,bottom for elements inside to move them to where i want them to be.But i do agree with your answer,So accepting it :)